# Create extension for user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

My DB has two users, the superuser and a (non-superuser) worker. I've installed the tsm_system_rows extension using `CREATE EXTENSION tsm_system_rows;` on the superuser, and I can use the new functionality in queries from this user. However, the worker user does not appear to be able to do the same:

```
worker=> SELECT * FROM customer_services TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(2);
ERROR:  tablesample method system_rows does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM customer_services TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(2);
```

Is there some extra step I need to do to allow my worker user to be able to use this extension?

Comment: Did you create the extension in the correct database?  Extensions are not cluster-wide.  You need to create them in each database where they will be used.

Comment: Yep that was the problem, thanks